# Div element misbehave

Tags: html, css, css-position

My second inner div position is weirdly adjusted when my first inner div have a long link text. How to fix it?

My html code:

```
<div class='div-wrapper'>
    <div class='inner-div1'>
        <a href="#">This is a long link</a>
    </div>
    <div class='inner-div2'>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css code:

```
.div-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height:70px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

.div-wrapper div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 90px;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}

.div-wrapper div a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

link to the picture of the div:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9zs4mgj7izuqsp1/question.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your CSS. Particularly the `.div-wrapper div`
You need to change the display setting from `inline-block` to `inline-table` to get it inside the cell. You mentioned that you wanted the box inside the larger box, but you need to clarify how exactly you want the inner boxes to be placed inside the larger box (ex: small gap between the boxes, both perfectly fit inside the large box with equal sizes)

Comment: Wow, you are brilliant, tq so much..:)

Comment: No problem :). Be sure to not use `px` units for the width and height. It's typically bad design because it will not look good in all screen resolutions. Use Google Chrome's inspect and play around with `%` values on the right side where the CSS properties are located.

Comment: `vertical-align: top;` will also solve the problem without using `dispaly: inline-table`

Comment: Hi there, need your help again. I want to use line-height in the inner-div to make the whole inner div clickable and vertically align the words, but again it breaks the whole thing. Any idea how to tackle this issue. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi. Thanks for accepting my answer :). You can try wrapping the `div` tag inside the anchor tag `<a>` and write your text in between the div tags.

Answer (score 1):

Just changed `inline-block` to `inline-flex` for your inner `div` and looks fine.

```css
.div-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height:70px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.div-wrapper div {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.div-wrapper div a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='div-wrapper'>
  <div class='inner-div1'>
    <a href="#">This is a long link</a>
  </div>
  <div class='inner-div2'>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, it's also works. But how if i want to use line-height to 60px in the inner div to make the whole div clickable and vertically align the words? It somehow breaks the whole things again..

Comment: I will need to see the issue that you faced.

Answer (score 1):

Just have to fix this, I don't think any solution here explains why the problem exists. Just to add up, the problem with this is because **vertical-align is set to baseline** by default.

What you have to do is set the **vertical-align to top**

Insert it in your CSS:

```
.div-wrapper div {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Link to solution: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnvgkfz3/

Answer (score 0):

Small changes in CSS

```
    .div-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: auto;
    height:70px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

.div-wrapper div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 190px;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}

.div-wrapper div a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```